Apex program salesforce
Can we create parameterized procedure for standard objects in Salesforce like contact, account, opportunity etc.. attached is the screenshot of one of the business logic which I want to call out using execute anonymous window. I'm new to Salesforce.
Below is the code from which I am trying to insert record using parameterized procedure...
public class AccHelper 
{

    Public static void Accountrecordinsertion (String aName, String aRating, String aIndustry, String aWebsite, String aPhone, 
                                              String aFax, String aNumber, String aSite, String aOwnership, String aType,
                                              Decimal aRevenue, String aActive, integer aNoofEmployee, String aBillingCity, String aBillingcountry,
                                             String aPostalcode, String aState, String aStreet, string aDescription, string aPriority, String aSLA string aUpsellOpportunity
                                             String aNumberofLocation)

    {
    
        {
            Account accRecord = new Account();
            
                accRecord.Name = aName;
                accRecord.Rating = aRating;
                accRecord.Industry = aIndustry;
                accRecord.Website = aWebsite;
                accRecord.Phone = aPhone;
                accRecord.Fax = aFax;
                accRecord.AccountNumber = aNumber;
                accRecord.Site = aSite;
                accRecord.Ownership = aOwnership;
                accRecord.Type = aType;
                accRecord.AnnualRevenue = aRevenue;
                accRecord.Active__c = aActive;
                accRecord.NumberOfEmployees = aNoofEmployee;
                accRecord.BillingCity = aBillingCity;
                accRecord.BillingCountry = aBillingcountry;
                accRecord.BillingPostalCode = aPostalcode;
                accRecord.BillingState = aState;
                accRecord.BillingStreet = aStreet;
                accRecord.Description = aDescription;
                accRecord.CustomerPriority__c = aPriority;
                accRecord.SLA__c = aSLA;
                accRecord.UpsellOpportunity__c = aUpsellOpportunity;
                accRecord.NumberofLocations__c = aNumberofLocation;
            insert accRecord;
            
            if(accRecord.Id != NULL)
                system.debug('Account record has been inserted successfully, with Id..: '+ accRecord.Id);
                       
        }
    }
}
Below is the invoking which i am using.
AccHelper acc = new Acc Helper();
acc.Accountrecordinsertion(here i am passing all the values...);


As you are using a static method in your AccHelper class, you do not need to create an instance in order to call the method.
You can invoke in below way:
AccHelper.Accountrecordinsertion(pass values as parameters).
Also, you can improve your code. For instance, the general convention in Apex is to follow camelCase for method names. It would be better to rename your method to accountRecordInsertion.

Thank you for adding your comments, sure i will try improving my code and will use cameCase while creating class. Thanks you...!
